# Google Sheets QUERY IMPORTRANGE formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P-rNwTP23hgx5Tud5vrqX_0a-gyoNEvQZqRGojRGL3M/edit#gid=1642961486)I'm trying to get a return of all Active jobs but I keep getting the error message #value!; "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: A". Here is the formula I used.

=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("SheetKey","employeeName1!A18:V1000"); IMPORTRANGE("SheetKey","employeeName2!A19:V1000");IMPORTRANGE("SheetKey","employeeName3!A19:V1000");IMPORTRANGE("SheetKey","employeeName4!A19:V1000")},"SELECT A, B, C, D, E WHERE E = 'Active'")

Comment: Please provide a sample sheet for replication of the issue.

Comment: I added a link in the comment

Comment: The sheet you've provided is inaccessible.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P-rNwTP23hgx5Tud5vrqX_0a-gyoNEvQZqRGojRGL3M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It should work now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried replicating your issue by making a copy of your provided sample sheet but apparently, the formula works after making a copy of the sheet. Please see attached screenshot.

[image]

I suggest trying to copy it first making a new sheet with the same content and see if it will also solve your problem.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I'll try that and see if works.

Comment: That still didn't work. Deleted and tried again and still got the same error

Comment: Have you tried making a copy of your entire google sheet? Go to File->Make a copy?

Comment: I did and that didn't do anything

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=QUERY({
 IMPORTRANGE("SheetKey", "employeeName1!A18:V1000"); 
 IMPORTRANGE("SheetKey", "employeeName2!A19:V1000");
 IMPORTRANGE("SheetKey", "employeeName3!A19:V1000");
 IMPORTRANGE("SheetKey", "employeeName4!A19:V1000")},
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5
  where Col5 = 'Active'")
```

Comment: Still getting the same error after making the edits

Comment: Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col2

Comment: @MitchellBivens error indicates that one or all importranges were not authorized. each individual importrange needs to be run separately first and access needs to be allowed

Comment: Tried it with the query still in the formula. Let me just try with =importrange and see what that does. I'll update you and let you know if that works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I took out the IMPORTRANGE and just used a query formula for the other sheets and it worked perfect. Thanks for the input everybody.